# Are specific programming questions pertaining to implementing a compiler/interpreter on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Suppose someone is trying to implement a compiler or interpreter. They are encountering a programming error and need debugging help. Would such questions be on-topic here, or are those more suited for [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such questions should not be considered on-topic for this site. The fact that the bug occurs in a compiler or interpreter doesn't mean that the question is *about* compilers or interpreters.

Questions like these will really be about some detail of the host language (the one the compiler or interpreter is implemented in), not the language being implemented.

Answer (score 3):

### No

Such questions are just the right fit for Stack Overflow. We should not accept such questions here because if we did, we would have some overlaps with SO and it'd be confusing where to post.

Answer (score 1):

### No, but...

If the question is specifically "some important/standard algorithm doesn't seem to work in this case", then it *could* be on topic.

[Here is a real-world example](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124405/loop-local-variable-in-cytrons-ssa-algorithm) of a question that is phrased as "there's a bug in my compiler", but I think would be on topic here.

The line that I would draw is that if we would need to look at the source code of your compiler to help you, it's off topic. Otherwise, it might be on topic.